# Sonatype Nexus OSS 3 - control the URL?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

We have just installed Sonatype Nexus 3.1.0-04. It should take over from an older V2 that isn't working correct. Issue is that the URL in V3 seems to be something we cannot control? I would not like to have to change URL for all developers and build servers...

The old URL was something like "http://packages.mycorp.com:24500/nexus/service/local/nuget/mycorp/" while the new (V3) is "http://packages.mycorp.com:24500/repository/nuget-group/"

Any way to force the URL in V3 to be the same as in V2?

Answer (score 3):

You can [add the context path /nexus](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/install.html#config-context-path) and add the [support for the legacy content URL format](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/install.html#config-legacy-url).

But that wont work for the service local URLs... only /content URL. So you will be able to get it to be an equivalent deployment to some degree only .. depending on your integrations and usage.